# Sleep fails, can't load crash dump driver

Tags: windows-7, firefox, sleep

Despite lots of analysis, I can't figure out why my PC fails to sleep.  Any method of triggering sleep (e.g. through windows menu; timeout; windows API call) is the same.  The screen briefly turns black, then immediately wakes up again.  Somehow this seems related to Firefox - if I close Firefox, I can sleep.  The problem is intermittent, in that often I can sleep fine.  However if I have left my PC idle, and it fails once, Windows will retry sleeping every 5s and fail time and again.  It seems more likely to occur with lots of Firefox tabs open and after Firefox has been running for some time.

The event log contains event ID 45, "The system could not sucessfully load the crash dump driver".

I have searched for answers containing this log and already tried:

- [Windows 7 migration led to crashdump and hibernate problems](https://superuser.com/questions/475966/windows-7-migration-led-to-crashdump-and-hibernate-problems): DumpFilters key is empty
- [Cause of Windows 7 "The system could not sucessfully load the crash dump driver"?](https://superuser.com/questions/98377/cause-of-windows-7-the-system-could-not-sucessfully-load-the-crash-dump-driver): It's not a mirrored drive

The full XML view of the event is:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="volmgr" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49156">45</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-28T14:14:39.903250600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>85253</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>AS5</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>\Device\HarddiskVolume3</Data> 
  <Binary>0000000001000000000000002D0004C003200000170000C000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

According to "fsutil resource info c:", c: is HarddiskVolume3.  This is a Samsung SSD.

I also have several warnings in my event log like this:

> wuaueng.dll (1004) SUS20ClientDataStore: The database page read from
>   the file "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb" at
>   offset 98304 (0x0000000000018000) (database page 2 (0x2)) for 32768
>   (0x00008000) bytes failed verification. Bit 199586 was corrupted and
>   has been corrected.  This problem is likely due to faulty hardware and
>   may continue. Transient failures such as these can be a precursor to a
>   catastrophic failure in the storage subsystem containing this file. 
>   Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing
>   the problem.

I have my doubts about this advice - will the hardware vendor really be likely to help me if I contact them?  I'm not sure this second log bears any relation to my principle problem in any case.

Please can anyone recommend a next step?  Let me know any more info I should upload.  Many thanks.

**Updates**

- I have tried powercfg with lots of different option.  Only the keyboard is set to wake and I don't touch it.  But it doesn't actually even seem to even sleep in the first place.  The powercfg -lastwake is "Power Button", so presumably when I turned my PC on in the first place.
- I updated my first para to clarify that the sleep failure will occur time and again.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep process is related with your CPU activity, if the activity is above a specific threshold, 10-20% for a period of scan that windows does, this condition delay the sleep time.

Or maybe a device wrongly make the wake up as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976877?wa=wsignin1.0#disabledevice)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will update my question: I did try powercfg, with lots of different options.  CPU is an interesting idea.  But I'm not sure the CPU could be busy time and time again?  And if the sleep was delayed, I don't think I would see it try to sleep then wake.  And it wouldn't generate the event??

Comment: here is an explanation for the idle state on windows, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx , if the pc can't fulfill the idle state than the pc can't go to sleep -IMHO

Comment: This article seems to be about task idle and the task scheduler scheduling idle tasks.  I'm not sure that is the same as sleep, which the article doesn't seem to mention.  E.g. "Task Scheduler verifies that the computer is in an idle state every 15 minutes" - but a PC can be set to sleep after a shorter time than 15 minutes.

Comment: as i know the sleep is related with idle state, if you set the sleep time at 1 minute it will monitor for at least a half of the time at 30 sec for the state of machine and than take the decision